# Unexpected error when programming OOP in PHP?

Tags: php, session, fatal-error

For some reason I get this error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 36 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\school\blom\inlog
>   dinkie\engine\class.php on line 13

On this piece of code:

```
<?php

class gebruiker extends start{

    private $_login_form;
    public $log_in;
    public $logged_in;

    function __construct(){

        $this->logged_in = false;

        $this->_login_form = new login_form();

        parent::html($this->_login_form);

    }

    function log_in(){

        $html = $this->_login_form;

        if($this->log_in){

            $go = true;
            if(!$_REQUEST['naam']){
                $this->_login_form->error_naam = 'vul je naam in!';
                $go = false;
            }
            else{
                $this->_login_form->naam = $_REQUEST['naam'];
            }

            if(!$_REQUEST['pass']){
                $this->_login_form->error_pass = 'vul je pass in!';
                $go = false;
            }
            else{
                $this->_login_form->pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];
            }
            //go log in

            $html = $dom->saveHTML();
        }

        parent::html($this->_login_form->form());
    }

}

class login_form extends gebruiker{

    protected $html;
    protected $error_naam = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    protected $error_pass = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    protected $naam = ''; 
    protected $pass = '';

    function form(){
        $this->html = ' <center>
                            <div style="border:1px dotted rgb(169, 169, 169); width:572px; height:196px; background-color:rgba(40, 152, 250, 0.670588);margin-top:200px;">
                                <h4 id="title">Inloggen</h4>
                                <br>
                                <form action="./?login" method="post">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td id="error_naam">'.$error_naam.'</td>
                                        <td id="error_pass">'.$error_pass.'</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input id="naam" type="text" placeholder="naam" name="naam" value="'.$naam.'" /></td>
                                        <td><input id="pass" type="password" placeholder="wachtwoord" name="pass" value="'.$pass.'" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="submit" value="Inloggen" /></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>  
                        </center>';
        return $this->html;
    }
}

?>
```

This is an back-end of this:

```
<?php

include_once('engine/database.php');
include_once('engine/class.php');

$start = new start();

class start{

    private $_html;

    function __construct(){

        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['gebruiker'])){

            if(isset($_REQUEST['login'])){
                $_SESSION['gebruiker']->log_in = true;
                $_SESSION['gebruiker']->log_in();
            }
            elseif(isset($_REQUEST['register'])){
                //register
            }
            elseif(!$_SESSION['gebruiker']->logged_in){
                $_SESSION['gebruiker']->log_in = false;
                $_SESSION['gebruiker']->log_in();
            }
            else{
                switch($_REQUEST['actie']){
                    case 'iets':
                        //dostuf
                        break;
                    default:

                        echo 'deafauasdfasdr';

                        break;
                }                   
            }
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['gebruiker'] = new gebruiker();
            //$new = new gebruiker();
        }
    }

    protected function html($html = 'emty'){
        $this->_html = $html;
    }

    function __destruct(){
        echo $this->_html;
    }

}

?>
```

Now I think that I get this error because I store the `gebruiker()` class inside a `$_SESSION`. I do not declare a lot of code so I don't understand why I reach a memory limit.

Or is it because I can't store a functional class with so many extends inside a `$_SESSION`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A memory allocation failure such as yours is usually due to an infinite recursion, in your case on line 13 (as specified by the error). The issue is due to constructor inheritance.

When you extend a class, you also inherit the extended class's constructor if the said constructor is public (though defining a new one in your extending class overrides it). In your case, the flow goes as follows:

- You create a start object
- Your start object creates a gebruiker
- Your gebruiker objects creates a login_form object (*Which extends gebruiker and has no reason to do so*), does not have an explicit constructor, and therefore runs gebruiker::__construct() on creation
- This object creates a login_form of its own.

This is where the infinite loop is happening.

Two ways to fix it:

**Remove the inheritance:**
You lose  nothing by doing so, as your login_form just outputs static HTML and does not actually require a single function of gebruiker.

**Add an explicit constructor definition to login_form**: This will prevent the parent constructor from running.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok I understand and I solved the problem. This is new for me so thank you for the clear explanation. I am any way reviewing my code. Storing a entire object inside a SESSION was an stupid id any way so I restart from scratch. I now understand more of the OOP concept thank you! PS, wow you answered this with 1 reputation! I am the first who has benefits form your knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

Thats because you get recursion in the constructor of `gebruiker`. You create in the constructor of gebruiker a new login_form object, which inherits from gebruiker and because you inherit the `__construct` method of gebruiker as well, you create more and more login_forms and finally a memory error

Comment: Ah yes, but how can I use protected so I can still use the properties of login_form. Or shall I just make them all public?

Comment: @sirwilliam You should revise the architecture of this part of you application.

Comment: You misunterstood the oop concept - you use inheritance to create a hierachtical class structure - in your case, you have just utility methods inside login_form which dont use anything from the parent classes. Just remove the `extends` and your class should work fine

Comment: Oke I done so. Note that this is the first time I start using OOP